# What does "attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'" mean?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to plot a point and a line segment in ggplot using `geom_point` and `geom_segment()`. The complication is that the line segment goes from 2019 or 2020 or 2021 on the x-axis, depending on whether there were data in that year or not. The first year that has data (i.e., there is a row where the `year` variable for that year exists) is the horizontal position of the start of the line segment. The data looks like this. (Actually, there are 43 network_ids; I'm drawing one point and segment for each id.)

```
  network_id   intrcpt       slope interceptx  sim2019  sim2020   sim2021   
1          1 0.9008887 -0.05032728       2021 1.001543 0.951216 0.9008887
2          1 0.9008887 -0.05032728       2021 1.001543 0.951216 0.9008887
3          1 0.9008887 -0.05032728       2021 1.001543 0.951216 0.9008887
  sim2022   year    
1 0.8505614 2019 
2 0.8505614 2021 
3 0.8505614 2022
```

I'm thinking I'd plot it like this:

```
    resfil0 <- foo %>%
         group_by(network_id) %>%
         mutate(left.seg.y=ifelse(any(year==2019), quo(sim2019),
                                    ifelse(any(year==2020), quo(sim2020), quo(sim2021))),
                left.seg.x=ifelse(any(year==2019), 2019,
                                  ifelse(any(year==2020), 2020, 2021))
                )

ggplot(resfil0, aes(x=2021, y=intrcpt, label=network_id)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_segment(aes(x=left.seg.x, y=!!left.seg.y, xend=2022, yend=sim2022)
```

But for some reason, I'm getting this error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `left.seg.end = ifelse(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: network_id = 1.
Caused by error in `rep()`:
! attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'
```

I have no idea what this means, what the problem is, or how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide your test data as the output from `dput`.  Why are you `quo`ting your column names?  That looks odd.  Your data frame is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) because your column names contain information (the year) you need for your plot.  `ggplot` is designed to work with tidy data.  Making it so is likely to help resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I thought I needed to put column names is quosures. It worked perfectly well to just put the column names in the `mutate` statement. Just making it more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks @Limey for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `quo` in `mutate` which you can leave out, you can also leave out the `!!` in `aes`. `ggplot` can directly access the variables in the provided data.frame, no need to make it more complicated than it is.

```
foo <- read.table(text = "network_id   intrcpt       slope interceptx  sim2019  sim2020   sim2021   sim2022   year
1          1 0.9008887 -0.05032728       2021 1.001543 0.951216 0.9008887  0.8505614 2019 
2          1 0.9008887 -0.05032728       2021 1.001543 0.951216 0.9008887  0.8505614 2019
3          1 0.9008887 -0.05032728       2021 1.001543 0.951216 0.9008887  0.8505614 2022")

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

resfil0 <- foo %>%
  group_by(network_id) %>%
  mutate(left.seg.y=ifelse(any(year==2019), sim2019,
                           ifelse(any(year==2020), sim2020, sim2021)),
         left.seg.x=ifelse(any(year==2019), 2019,
                           ifelse(any(year==2020), 2020, 2021))
  )

ggplot(resfil0, aes(x=2021, y=intrcpt, label=network_id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=left.seg.x, y=left.seg.y, xend=2022, yend=sim2022))
```